# R: How to compact a data frame by outputting the count for an ID, while still reporting the rest of the values for that ID

Tags: r

If I have the data set:

```
X1 = 6:10
X2 = c(2,2,4,5,5)
X3 = c(.1,.1,.1,.7,.7)

df = data.frame(X1,X2,X3)

X1 X2  X3
1  6  2 0.1
2  7  2 0.1
3  8  4 0.1
4  9  5 0.7
5 10  5 0.7
```

Is there away to compact the data frame by showing the count of X2, which would be an identifier, while showing the corresponding values for X3, and other linked rows?

Comment: Perhaps `split(df$X3, df$X2)` where the list names are key

Comment: What if for the same id (X2) you have different X3 values ? And how do you want to show X1 values in a single row ? Can you post your expected result based on this example ?